# Prevent application from being copied/generate activation password

Tags: java, database, passwords, activation

I made a Java (on IntelliJ IDEA) application and I want to give it to someone via USB or Dropbox.

However I don't want him to give it to someone else, like you know, he downloaded the file, so he can copy/paste it to his USB and give it to more people.

Is there any way to prevent the application from being copied after I give him the application? At first I thought of making a login window, but then I thought "hey, if he knows the password to login to application, he can just give the application to someone and give him the password as well", so login window is not an option (I think?). Can I disable the copy/cut functions with If statements after being copied once?

Or I can only prevent it by linking my application with a database and generating unique passwords to activate my application? Like for example, someone requested to use my application, so I will give him the application but he won't be able to run it. Then I generate a password and sent him the password. However that password can only be used once so if he will try to use the same password on 2 different PCs, it will give him an error. Is there any guide/tutorial/tips of making something like that on Java?

Comment: Google "software copy protection".

Answer (score 1):

You could create some kind of "activation code" for your software that is generated based on some information about the hardware it's running on. I've seen some people using, for example, the MAC address, that you can obtain in a platform-independent way in Java.

However, keep in mind that those techniques will only work against the most basic users. MAC addresses can be easily changed by anyone that knows how to use Google and even if you use something incredibly complicated instead of MAC addresses, Java programs are dead simple to decompile and once the attacker knows what function is checking if the program is correctly activated, he/she can easily replace it. Yes, you can obfuscate your bytecode, but it only makes the task a little harder, not impossible.

You can do what you suggested and use passwords that can only be used once, but then your program needs to know that it has been activated, by storing that information somewhere (a file or something like that). And once the user knows where that information is stored, it can be replicated on other computers.

Unfortunately, once the user has your program, you have no control over what he/she can do. You can make sure that the user is not going to do stuff he/she is not supposed to do with your program by not giving him/her the program at all. You can, for example, expose your program's features through the web. But, as you said, nothing stops an user from sharing login credentials with another person. Yes, you could check if the user is accessing the page from a different IP address, but then a legitimate user could have problems when, for example, accessing your program from a different wifi network. And in this case, your protection not only fails in solving the problem, but also becomes annoying to a honest user.

In summary, brilliant engineers at huge software companies have been working on protections for their software for years and I'm yet to see a software that cannot be illegally activated given enough time and effort.